# iPhone Google Docs API issue

Tags: iphone

I am working on one sample app in which I need to use Google Docs API. I have found GoogleDocs demo app. But I am facing one authentication issue in login process. I am getting following error.

```
<GDataServiceGoogleDocs: 0x1e4f00> objectFetcher:<GDataHTTPFetcher: 0x1eb930> failedWithStatus:403 data:<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceForbiddenException</code><internalReason>403.4 SSL required</internalReason></error></errors>
```

and so I am not getting access token from Google.

I did some research regarding but not getting success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using http in your urls, please change to https. In general all 
your requests to the APIs should use https.

Please refer to [this](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2011/09/requiring-ssl-for-documents-list.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Based on "SSL required": did you try the https: schema in your query URL?

Comment: yes , In google docs api they already check the condition (Https)

Comment: the authentication process has little to do with the protocol (http vs https). so did you solve the problem?